# Responsive Image Gallery: Last thumbnail goes to next line

Tags: jquery, html, css, thumbnails, image-gallery

I am using a responsive gallery script with thumbnails carousel.
I installed the script & it's running perfectly, except 1 small problem.
In the thumbnails carousel, last thumbnail goes to a new line, while, it should remain aligned horizontally with all other thumbnails. Please have a look at the attached image.[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPM8j.jpg)

I didn't change anything in the actual script code (not even the HTML), except changed some background colors in the CSS file.

Can someone please guide me how can I fix that thumbnail issue?

Thank you very much.

---

CODE UPLOADED - Click on below link

---

As there are a lot of JS & CSS files for this gallery, I am not able to put all the code files here. However, I just uploaded the page, please [CLICK HERE TO VIEW THE GALLERY PAGE](http://uzairusman.com/gallery/gallery.html).

Comment: We need to see the code or there is no way to debug it.

Comment: If you didn't change anything in the plugin code it must be a conflict or something with your existing html or css. Please post the code you're using.

Comment: Could you reproduce your problem in a jsfiddle? As well as adding some code here

Comment: Hello experts, I just uploaded the code, link is provided in the question's description. Please have a look.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!